# UIScrollView pages content not working properly - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I've been trying for one whole day to make it work right. I tried different tutos and made adjustments (searching in here) but it doesnt work properly.

On iphone 5s, it almost works right, excepts for the last page that it seems to add "half" of a page on scroll view. The green part is the background color of the scroll view and it doesn't bounce back.

[image]

On iphone 6, the content is all messed up and instead of having 5 images, it has only 4 and a half (i cant scroll it anymore and it doesn't bounce back).

[image]

If I press continue, it works perfectly on both screen sizes. It is only the swipe option that is not working properly.

Here is the code where I put the images inside the scroll view.

```
func loadContent() {
    var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    for i in 0..<imageArr.count { // is 5
        frame.origin.x = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
        let image = UIImage(named: imageArr[i])
        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        imageView.image = image
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        self.scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
    }
}
///Function of Continue button
@IBAction func nextImage(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.scrollView.contentOffset.x = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(self.pageControl.currentPage+1)
    }
}
```

I've been searching for 4 hours for a solution but nothing seems to work.

**[Edit]: With the answer of TheFuquan I could solve the problem.**

**[Obs:]** if you searching about the messed content, these lines of code can help you. All the tutos that I saw didn't have these lines and the content just wouldnt align perfect and this solved:

```
    imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleTopMargin]
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: better option was to use collection view with horizontal scroll.

Comment: can you please show how you are instantiating the scrollView?

Comment: @StefanStefanov I'm using storyboard. I put a scrollview, add some contraints (margin left, right top and bottom) and I reference it on my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a typical problem that i face each time i try to load some dynamic content inside a view.

If you re calling your function `loadContent` from `viewDidLoad`, then you should call your `loadContent` inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Be aware that unlike `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidLayoutSubviews` may get called multiple times, so have a flag to ensure that your `loadContent` gets invoked only once.

```
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        guard self.didLoadContent == false else {
            return
        }

        self.didLoadContent = true
        loadContent()
    }
```

this way you let the view loaded from your storyboard to resize the iPhone's size.

Comment: This worked for me. I believe it has to do with the resing of the views. Thanks man.

Answer (score 3):

Why is the following line in your `for loop`:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
```

You should do this before the `for loop` like this:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * imageArr.count
```

Comment: @nathan  This answer may not solve the problem but it’s definitely correct, you should set the content view only once outside the for loop as mentioned here